# JQuery: .LOAD, how to get next call to happen AFTER the .LOAD completes?

Tags: php, jquery

JQuery: .LOAD, how to get next call to happen AFTER the .LOAD completes?

Basicly Im loading some information into a div which is dynamically adjusting the height of the DIV as it loads.

I then want to run a call to adjust the height of the DIV, but can only properly calculate after the load completes in full.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) a callback like so:

```
$('#result').load('http://wherever-youre-loading-from.com', function() {
   // resize result div here
});
```